# Custom Euler method implementation always tends to infinity

Tags: python, math

I have a system of differential equations:

[image]

I'm using the following code to run Euler's method:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

def f(s,t):
    a = 0.63
    b = 0.02

    g = 0.61
    d = 0.015

    h = s[1]
    l = s[2]

    # print(s)

    # prey
    dhdt = a * h - b * h * l

    # predator
    dldt = d * h * l - g * l

    return [dhdt, dldt]

# s0=[24.2, 16.16]

# h = 1
# t = np.arange(0, 1 + h, h) # Numerical grid

# Explicit Euler Method
# s = [[1890, s0[0], s0[1]]]
# s[0] = s0

result = [
    [1890, 24.2, 16.16]
]

for i in range(40):
    # s[i + 1] = s[i] + h*f(t[i], s[i])
    [dhdt, dldt] = f(result[i], i)
    # print(f(result[i], i))
    # print([dhdt, dldt])
    latest = [1890+1+i, result[i][1] + dhdt, result[i][2] + dldt]

    result.append(latest)
    print(result[-1])
```

However, this always tends to infinity (printing result[-1] every iteration):

[image]

However, when I use scipy's odeint, it works perfectly fine:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

def f(s,t):
    a = 0.63
    b = 0.02

    g = 0.61
    d = 0.015

    h = s[0]
    l = s[1]

    # prey
    dhdt = a * h - b * h * l

    # predator
    dldt = d * h * l - g * l

    return [dhdt, dldt]

t = np.linspace(0,45)
s0=[24.2, 16.16]

s = odeint(f,s0,t)
s = np.insert(s, 0, 0, axis=1)

for i in range(len(s)):
    # p: np.ndarray = s[i]
    # print(s[i])
    # pass
    s[i][0] = i+1890
    # print(s[i])

    # s[i].insert(0, i+1890)

# print(s)

prediction = pd.DataFrame(data=s, columns=['Year', 'Hare\'', 'Lynx\''])
prediction.set_index('Year', inplace=True)

url = 'http://people.whitman.edu/~hundledr/courses/M250F03/LynxHare.txt'
real = pd.read_csv(url, delim_whitespace=True, header=None, index_col=0)
real.index.name = 'Year'
real.columns = ['Hare', 'Lynx']

# Get the years from 1890 and onwards
real = real.iloc[45:]

print(prediction)
```

So what is it that odeint does differently? Why is mine tending to infinity?

I think there is something wrong with my mathematical formula (the euler's part in the for loop), but I can't seem to find the issue.

EDIT: Fixed. I reduced the step size and it worked!

Comment: I wonder why there is `t` in the `f(s,t)` as you never access it..? Is that intentional?

Comment: You have numerical instabilities due to a too large time step dt=1, which is common with Euler's forward method. Try reducing the time step or use another integration approach.

Comment: @np8 I don't access t, I've just left it there for the sake of convention (since in ODEs you might need t). I can remove it though.

Comment: @RemiCuingnet then how does odeint work?

Comment: @Berlm I only kown according to the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html) that is based on LSODA from the FORTRAN library ODEPACK. According to [this article](https://computing.llnl.gov/sites/default/files/ODEPACK_pub1_u88007.pdf), it either uses [Adams' method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_multistep_method) or the [Backward differentiation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backward_differentiation_formula) depending on the stiffness.